# Number of integers in an interval satisfying two linear congruences.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Suppose I have an interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$. Suppose I have two linear congruences $x \equiv a \pmod {N_1}$ and $x \equiv b \pmod{N_2}$. I am wondering what are the number of integers in the interval that satisfy these congruences? When $N_1$ and $N_2$ are coprime it is 
$$
\frac{|I|}{N_1 N_2} + O(1). 
$$
I was wondering what can we say when $N_1$ and $N_2$ are not coprime. Any input is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If $N_1$ and $N_2$ are not coprime, the congruences can only be satisfied for certain values of $a$ and $b$. For instance, $x\equiv0\bmod6$ and $x\equiv1\bmod10$ cannot be simultaneously satified. A fraction $\frac1{\gcd(N_1,N_2)}$ of the pairs of residues modulo $N_1$ and $N_2$ yields simultaneously satisfiable congruences, and for such pairs, the number  of integers in $I$ that satisfy these congruences is

$$
\frac{|I|}{\operatorname{lcm}(N_1,N_2)}+O(1)\;.
$$

Incidentally, if you uniformly randomly select a pair of residues, the expected number of integers in $I$ that satisfy the resulting congruences is

$$
\frac1{\gcd(N_1,N_2)}\cdot\frac{|I|}{\operatorname{lcm}(N_1,N_2)}+O(1)=\frac{|I|}{N_1N_2}+O(1)\;,
$$

the same as for coprime $N_1$ and $N_2$.